# using partial typemaps from numpy.i

Tags: python, c++, numpy, swig

I have a function that needs only one of the dimensions of an input array, so I am ignore a dimension in a 2D numpy array.
Is there a way to do this?

**Header:**

```
#ifndef __nparrtest_h__
#define __nparrtest_h__
class NPArrTest {
public:
    static void Print2D(int n, int m, const int* graph);
};
#endif
```

**Cpp:**

```
#include "NPArrTest.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void NPArrTest::Print2D(int n, int m, const int* graph) {
     printf("n: %d m: %d\n",n,m);
}
```

**swig interface file:**

```
%module NPArrTest
%{
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
    #include "NPArrTest.h"
%}
%include "numpy.i"
%init %{
  import_array1();
%}
%numpy_typemaps(int,    NPY_INT   , int)
//Something like the below:
%apply int DIM2, int* IN_ARRAY2 {int m, const int* graph};
%include "NPArrTest.h"
```

I can't get `%apply (int DIM1, int* IN_ARRAY2) {(int m, const int* graph)};` or `%apply int* IN_ARRAY2 {const int* graph};` to work (the ladder to just pass the 2D array).

How can I pass only a single dimension length value of the 2D array to the c++ function?

>

P.S. Is there an easy way to allow this conversion?

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'

Comment: What is 'single dimension of a 2d array'?  Just one row or column?  All the values flattened into 1d?

Comment: If the array is KxM I want to send M to the function and the other parameter to the function is user defined.

Comment: Let me clarify a bit more. I am sending the entire array (pointer) but instead of providing both dimension lengths as integers I wish to send only one. So if I have a user defined value n and 2d array 'graph' with dimensions kxm I want a Python function with call that looks like Print2D(n, np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])), the C call will look like Print2D(int n, int m, const int *graph)

Comment: That is a 2D array in python

Comment: I have extended the numpy.i typemaps with a typemap `(DATA_TYPE*   DYNARGOUTVIEW_ARRAY2_FIXED[ANY], DIM_TYPE* DIM1)` where one dimension is fixed. Let me know, if this is what you want

Comment: That seems like a reasonable solution. In this case its an input array.
Please send it.
RIght now my solution is to use another helper function that has an extra argument thats ignored.  I add `static inline void Print2D(int n, int m, int k, const int* graph) { Print2D(n, m, graph);}' and use `%apply (int DIM1, int DIM2, int* IN_ARRAY2) {(int m, int k, const int* graph)};'.  I need to somehow ignore the original function though...

Answer (score 0):

I have done similarly for an output array for which one of the dimensions were fixed. The code below is part of an extension I have made for numpy.i

```
#ifdef SWIGPYTHON
%{
#ifndef SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#  define NO_IMPORT_ARRAY
#endif
#include "stdio.h"
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
%}

%include "numpy.i"

%define %numpy_ex_typemaps(DATA_TYPE, DATA_TYPECODE, DIM_TYPE)

/* Typemap suite for (DATA_TYPE** DYNARGOUTVIEW_ARRAY2_FIXED[ANY], DIM_TYPE* DIM1)
 */
%typemap(in,numinputs=0,noblock=1)
(DATA_TYPE* DYNARGOUTVIEW_ARRAY2_FIXED[ANY], DIM_TYPE* DIM1)
{
  size_t secondDim = $1_dim0;
  size_t firstDim;
  DATA_TYPE* tempData;
  $1 = &tempData;
  $2 = &firstDim;
}
%typemap(out)
void DYNARGOUTVIEW_ARRAY2_FIXED_##DATA_TYPECODE
{
  npy_intp dims[2] = {(npy_intp) firstDim, (npy_intp) secondDim};
%#ifdef __GNUC__
  __extension__
%#endif
  PyObject * array = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, dims, DATA_TYPECODE,(void*)(tempData));
  if (!array) SWIG_fail;
  $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result,array);
}

%enddef    /* %numpy_ex_typemaps() macro */

%numpy_ex_typemaps(double            , NPY_DOUBLE   , size_t)
%numpy_ex_typemaps(float             , NPY_FLOAT    , size_t)
%numpy_ex_typemaps(signed char       , NPY_BYTE     , size_t)
```

When you apply the typemap, you must match both typemaps, e.g.

```
%apply (double* DYNARGOUTVIEW_ARRAY2_FIXED[ANY], size_t* DIM1) {(double* coefs[3], size_t* length)};
%apply void DYNARGOUTVIEW_ARRAY2_FIXED_NPY_DOUBLE {void getFilter}
```

Your function looks like this.

```
void getFilter(double* coefs[3], size_t* length);
```

It should be clear from looking at the original numpy.i file to see how to change this to an input.